# How do you add angular script to chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to manipulate the text field in a website which is written in angular, through my chrome extension, when I do so from the context of chrome console, I'm able to do edit the text field etc, however, when I do it from the code of my extension, its just not happening and throws the error that angular is not defined, despite the fact that Ive added angular. 
P.S: I'm also using jQuery as part of my project.

Comment: How is this related to angular after all? Doesn't your browser render the page and you could access it through jQuery in any kind? What have you tried and what is not working yet?

Comment: How are you trying to access `angular` in the extension? It will be a property of the page window

Comment: You need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm actually trying to apply the best coupon on the click of a button (which the extension will append somewhere on the page). And the website is written in angular, So,  I needed to write the best coupon code in the text-field, and I'd have to write the angular equivalent for writing into the text-field. So, this is related to angular. And, I've tried creating a script variable, containing the script for angular and appending it to the document head. But to no gain.

Answer (score 0):

I actually feel so stupid for asking this. You just need to add the angular's file to the background_script.